# Who is the "caller" when calling Form Submit installable trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom, google-apps-script-addon

I have recently published a Google Forms add-on that access a Classroom Course roster right after the Form is submitted.

I manually installed the onSubmit trigger in my script and it worked fine. I copied the code to another Form and worked too, with GSuite and non-GSuite accounts.

The problem is that now that the add-on was published, I tested it and it doesn't work. Searching the GCP, in the Logs viewer I found a "The caller does not have permission at onSubmit(Code:40)" error from the API when calling the classroom method.

So, the trigger is working, but for some reason the permissions fail. I checked the scopes and they correctly request the appropriate permissions for the classroom method the onSubmit function calls. I'm wondering if the problem is that I manually installed the trigger and I should have it programmatically installed within the script.

Thoughts?

Comment: The add-on should definitely create the On Form Submit trigger programmatically.  I don't know if that's the problem, but I'd guess that it could be.  I've noticed that triggers installed programmatically from an add-on don't have any trigger function name shown in the dashboard.  I don't know why that is, but some kind of a distinction is being made between user created, and add-on created triggers.

Comment: Thank you @AlanWells, I believe the manually installed trigger works because the error comes from a call within the function that registers the trigger. My wonder is if the "caller" is me because I manually installed the trigger and if it was otherwise created by the add-on, then the "caller" would be the user who installs the add-on. This is based on "Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them." from [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions)

Comment: Quote from documentation: `Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them`  So, if you want the add-on code to run from the account that installed the add-on, then the trigger needs to be installed with code from the add-on.  But, I'm not sure what you are ultimately trying to achieve, and why you didn't put code in your add-on to install the On Form Submit trigger?  Did you want the add-on user to manually install a trigger that would run the add-on code?  Are you trying to get the add-on to run the code from your account?

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks again @AlanWells. I didn't programmatically installed the trigger because I'm a newbie and didn't know that I should do it that way. Now I know and I'll fix my add on.

Comment: It's easy to make a simple mistake when you're first learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the answer depends on whether the trigger was manually installed or programmatically installed. If it's the former, then the "caller" is whoever installed the trigger (typically the developer)  and if it's the later, then the "caller" is the user who installs the add-on (which was my intention).

Thanks Alan!